# Convert list of Function Arguments to an Array

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm working on a CMS, and I'm looking for a way to convert a list of function arguments, into an array. For example:

```
function testfunction($param1, $param2){
$string = "Param1: $param1  Param2: $param2";
return $string;
}

$funcname = 'testfunction';
$params = "'this is, parameter 1', 'this is parameter2'";

//This doesnt work, sends both parameters as the first, dont know why.
echo call_user_func($funcname, $params);


//So I want to split the parameter list:
$paramsarray = preg_split('%Complex Regex%', $params);

//And call thusly:
echo call_user_func_array($funcname, $paramsarray);
```

I dont know what kind of regex to use here....
I could just explode by ',' but that would explode all commas contained in strings, arrays etc...  So I need a regex to do this, I'm ok with regexes, but it seems like there would be a lot of rules in this.

Comment: Ok, I know about call_user_func_array, this example is very simplified.  The function name, and parameters are all dynamic, and not entered as an array in the first place.  Which is why I have to split them into an array.  I don't know why  call_user_func won't work for me, with multiple arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess if you really want to start from a string (instead of an array like others suggested), you could do:

In PHP 5.3:

```
$params = "'this is, parameter 1', 'this is parameter2'";
$paramsarray = str_getcsv($params, ',', "'");
```

In PHP 5.1/5.2:

```
$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
fwrite($fp, $params);
fseek($fp, 0);
$paramsarray = fgetcsv($fp, 0, ',', "'");

print_r($paramsarray);
```

...and get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => this is, parameter 1
    [1] => this is parameter2
)
```

...then use `call_user_func_array`.

If you want to use more complex types (e.g.: arrays or objects), that'll be a real challenge. You'll probably have to use the [Tokenizer](http://php.net/token_get_all).

Comment: Thanks!  This works for now, I didn't even know about Tokenizer functions...  I will have to look into that further.  for parameters like: testfunction('this is param1', array('one' => 'something', 'two' => 'something else'), 'and yet more', $someclass->somefunction('more parameters'));

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just use [func_get_args](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) for this?

Also, call_user_func I believe should be called like this:

```
    call_user_func('functionName', $param1, $param2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$params` is (in your case) a single variable, that contains a single value of type `string`. Its *not* an array or any other complex type. I assume, that you don't even need your `%Complex Regex%`.

```
$funcname = 'testfunction';
$params = "'this is, parameter 1', 'this is parameter2'";

foreach ($params as &$param) $param = trim($param, "' \n\r\t");

echo call_user_func_array($funcname, $params);
```

Comment: Yes, however this is just a very simple example.  I may define arrays, at some point.  So that creates a problem... Still not sure how to go about it in that case.

Comment: If you already have an array, you can just omit the `explode()` thing, because this just splits the string into an array. The interesting thing is `call_user_func_array()`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want [call_user_func_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) instead.

```
$params = array('this is, parameter 1', 'this is parameter2');
$funcname = 'testfunction';

echo call_user_func_array($funcname, $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe using [`call_user_func_array`](http://uk.php.net/call_user_func_array) instead.